# Сопоставить каждый элемент массива и суммировать их java

Tags: java, массивы, сравнение, числа

Есть 2 массива, наполненных случайными числами. Нужно 1-й элемент одного массива сравнить с 1-ым элементом второго массива, 2-ой элемент одного - со вторым элементом другого, и так все 10. Если элементы равны, нужно вывести сумму каждой пары и общую их сумму. Прописать каждый элемент вручную, конечно, можно, но это такие рельсы. Подскажите, через какой цикл и как лучше такое реализовать. Пока объявил так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mass1[]=new int[10];
    int mass2[]=new int[10];
    int sum=0;

    for (int i=0; i<mass1.length; i++) {
        mass1[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println(mass1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    for (int j=0; j<mass2.length; j++) {
        mass2[j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println(mass2[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Если элементы равны, нужно вывести сумму каждой пары и общую их сумму". Если честно, не совсем понятно

Comment: То есть, мы сравниваем x1 и y1, x2 и y2 (я примерные переменные присваиваю, это элементы массива по порядку просто). Выводим сумму каждой совпавшей пары, а затем - общую сумму всех совпавших пар.

Comment: Можно не использовать рандом, а вывести элементы массива в файлы, предварительно создав набор в Excel

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае совсем не обязательно создавать третий массив для подсчета суммы, впрочем как и 2 Randomа. Достаточно пройтись одним циклом и сопоставить элементы массивов с одинаковыми индексами.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr1 = new int[10];
    int[] arr2 = new int[10];
    Random r = new Random();
    int sum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) { // длины массивов совпадают, поэтому цикл 1
        arr1[x] = r.nextInt(5); // наполняем массив 1 случайными значениями до 5
        arr2[x] = r.nextInt(5); // наполняем массив 2 случайными значениями до 5
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1) + "\n" + Arrays.toString(arr2));

    for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) { // длины массивов совпадают, поэтому цикл 1
        if (arr1[x] == arr2[x]) { // поиск совпадений элементов на одинаковых индексах
            System.out.println("Sum of equal elements = " + arr1[x]*2); // вывод суммы
            sum += arr1[x] + arr2[x]; // значения добавляются в общую сумму
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total sum of equal elements in array = " + sum); //общая сумма
}
```

Answer (score 0):

рандом тут своеобразный...при одних и тех же значениях будут выпадать одни и те-же числа...поэтому такое при стандартном рандоме в принципе написать невозможно,если не писать свой рандом конечно...и мой тебе совет:не используй mach.random где нужны целые числа а не bolean,

```
public class НовыйClass {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
int mass1[] = new int[11];
int mass2[] = new int[11];
int rDop = 0;
int pDop = 0;
int OutPut = 0;
Random rand = new Random();
Random randOne = new Random(4);
while(pDop < 10){mass1[pDop] = randOne.nextInt(11);pDop++;}
while(rDop < 10){
mass2[rDop] = rand.nextInt(10);
if(mass1[rDop] == mass2[rDop]){
System.out.println(mass1[rDop] + "/" + mass2[rDop]);
OutPut = OutPut + mass1[rDop] + mass2[rDop];
rDop++;
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал немного иначе. Поочередные суммы элементов я вывел в отдельный массив и уже из него вывел общую сумму. Если кому-то будет интересно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int mass1[] = new int[10];
    int mass2[] = new int[10];
    int mass3[] = new int[10];
    int S=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mass1.length; i++) {

        mass1[i] = (int) (4+Math.random() * 5);
        System.out.println(mass1[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < mass2.length; j++) {

        mass2[j] = (int) (4+Math.random() * 5);
        System.out.println(mass2[j]);

    }

    System.out.println("\n");

    for (int n = 0; n < mass3.length; n++) {

            if (mass1[n] == mass2[n]) {

                mass3[n] = mass1[n] + mass2[n];
                System.out.println(mass3[n]);

            }

            else {

                mass3[n] = 0;
                System.out.println("совпадений нет");
            }

    }

    System.out.println("\n");

  for (int n = 0; n < mass3.length; n++) {
       S = S + mass3[n];
   }

   System.out.println(S);
}}
```